# Key and value reversed in JSON string sent to Django view via POST

Tags: javascript, django, json

This is my first attempt at ajax, and I've written a submit handler that parses a form and sends the data via POST to the server as a JSON string. Here is a simplified example of what my javascript looks like

```
formData = JSON.stringify({'testA':{'testa':'some data'},'testB':{'test2':'more data'}});
```

The JSON string looks like this

```
{"testA":{"test1":"some data"},"testB":{"test2":"more data"}}
```

and I send it via post here

```
$.post("/some/form/page/",formData,updateForm,'json');
```

On the server side is where the problem rears its ugly head, this is what my query dictionary looks like when I print if from the Django view

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"testA":{"test1":"some data"},"testB":{"test2":"more data"}}': [u'']}>
```

The JSON string is the key of the query dictionary. I am not very familiar with Javascript or JSON so don't be afraid of hurting my pride by pointing out an obvious newbie mistake, because I am and I know it. ;)

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending the *string* as a parameter to `$.post`. Instead of calling "JSON.stringify()" yourself, just pass in your raw JavaScript object as the second parameter to `$.post()`.

```
$.post("/some/form/page/", {'testA':{'testa':'some data'},'testB':{'test2':'more data'}}, updateForm, 'json');
```